# Crossfade Multiple Background Images Using CSS Only - Single Page Design

Tags: html, css, animation

I am building a responsive one-page website using multiple divs which scale to the height and width of the user's browser. I would like to have multiple background images crossfade into one other in an infinite loop within one of the divs on the website. I have attempted to follow this tutorial: http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/cfimg/ to the best of my ability, but have been unable to adapt it to my specific needs. I believe I am missing a piece of code from the tutorial that is integral to this system, but I can't for the life of me understand which parts I must and which parts I mustn't implement in order for this to work in this case. (In part due to my nooby-ness and in part due to the fact that the tutorial is oddly segmented.)

I am a total noob to Web Dev, so please forgive me (and correct me) if my code is terribly wrong.

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div id="home" class="panel">
            <div class="inner">
                <div id="backgroundchange">
                    <div id="back1"></div>
                    <div id="back2"></div>
                    <div id="back3"></div>
                    <div id="back4"></div>
                    <div id="back5"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    <body>
<html>

<!--Div Formatting-->

html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}

.panel {
    font-family: "Source Sans Pro", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    color: white;
    height: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    display: table;
    margin: 0;
    background: #1c1c1c;
    padding: 0 0;
}

.panel .inner {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

<!--Background Animation-->

#backgroundchange.backgroundimg {
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    transition: background-image 1s ease-in-out;
}

#back1 {
    background: url(../img/Back1.png) no-repeat center center fixed;
}

#back2 {
    background: url(../img/Back2.png) no-repeat center center fixed;
}

#back3 {
    background: url(../img/Back3.png) no-repeat center center fixed;
}

#back4 {
    background: url(../img/Back4.png) no-repeat center center fixed;
}

@keyframes cf4FadeInOut {
    0% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    17% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    25% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    92% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}

#backgroundchange div:nth-of-type(1) {
    animation-delay: 6s;
}
#backgroundchange div:nth-of-type(2) {
    animation-delay: 4s;
}
#backgroundchange div:nth-of-type(3) {
    animation-delay: 2s;
}
#backgroundchange div:nth-of-type(4) {
    animation-delay: 0;
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I believe this is what you want. I'm not sure what browser you're using but if it's a webkit browser like chrome be sure to use the `-webkit-` prefix on your css animations:

**HTML**

```
<div id="home" class="panel">
    <div class="inner">
        <div id="backgroundchange">
            <div class="backgroundimg" id="back1"></div>
            <div class="backgroundimg" id="back2"></div>
            <div class="backgroundimg" id="back3"></div>
            <div class="backgroundimg" id="back4"></div>
            <div class="backgroundimg" id="back5"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}

.panel {
    font-family: "Source Sans Pro", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    color: white;
    height: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    display: table;
    margin: 0;
    background: #1c1c1c;
    padding: 0 0;
}

.panel .inner {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.backgroundimg {
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;

}

#back1 {
    background: url("http://www.placecage.com/500/700") no-repeat center fixed;

}

#back2 {
    background: url("http://www.placecage.com/500/600") no-repeat center fixed;
}

#back3 {
    background: url("http://www.placecage.com/500/500") no-repeat center fixed;
}

#back4 {
    background: url("http://www.placecage.com/500/800") no-repeat center fixed;
}

#back5 {
    background: url("http://www.placecage.com/500/900") no-repeat center fixed;
}

@keyframes backgroundchangeFadeInOut {
  0% {
    opacity:1;
  }
  17% {
    opacity:1;
  }
  25% {
    opacity:0;
  }
  92% {
    opacity:0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity:1;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes backgroundchangeFadeInOut {
  0% {
    opacity:1;
  }
  17% {
    opacity:1;
  }
  25% {
    opacity:0;
  }
  92% {
    opacity:0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity:1;
  }
}
#backgroundchange div:nth-of-type(1) {
  animation-delay: 8s;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 8s;
}
#backgroundchange div:nth-of-type(2) {
  animation-delay: 6s;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 6s;
}
#backgroundchange div:nth-of-type(3) {
  animation-delay: 4s;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 4s;
}
#backgroundchange div:nth-of-type(4) {
  animation-delay: 2s;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 2s;
}

#backgroundchange div:nth-of-type(5) {
  animation-delay: 0;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0;
}

#backgroundchange div {
animation-name: backgroundchangeFadeInOut;
animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
animation-iteration-count: infinite;
animation-duration: 8s;

-webkit-animation-name: backgroundchangeFadeInOut;
-webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
-webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
-webkit-animation-duration: 8s;

}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/h2fzvyr5/)

Comment: Great stuff, @jmore009, but I noticed that the very first image in the sequence does not display - only the last 4.